# Install Pytorch CPU Only with pip that works on Apple machine as well as Linux

Tags: python, azure, pytorch

I'm getting install errors when I deploy a Flask app to Azure services. I've tracked the issue down to a `pip install torch` and likely being due to a CPU version.

I'm unable to find a way to install a CPU-only version of Pytorch that will install on both Macbook and Linux?

Answer (score 6):

That works for me:

```bash
python -m pip install torch --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
```